# MySQL Query: 3 tests passed, 1 failed

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that will pull students that have passed tests 1 thru 3 AND failed test 4.

Students can retake tests so there may be failed records, followed by passed records for some tests, such is the case with student_id = 2 below.

Table setup like this -

```
test_id | student_id | status  | completed_on
--------+------------+---------+------------
 1      |    1       | passed  | 2018-03-24 
 2      |    1       | passed  | 2018-03-25 
 3      |    1       | passed  | 2018-03-26 
 4      |    1       | failed  | 2018-03-27 
 1      |    2       | failed  | 2018-03-24 
 1      |    2       | passed  | 2018-03-25 
 2      |    2       | passed  | 2018-03-26 
 3      |    2       | passed  | 2018-03-27 
 4      |    2       | failed  | 2018-03-27
```

In this case the query should pull both student_id 1 and 2

I tried this but it obviously didn't work -

```
select * 
from table 
where (test_id = 1 and status = 'passed') 
and (test_id = 2 and status = 'passed') 
and (test_id = 3 and status = 'passed') 
and (test_id = 4 and status = 'failed')
```

Comment: Assuming that once the test is passed, it will not be attempted again, you can get the max(completed_on) for each group of test_id and student_id and then do your checks for those rows only.

Comment: @clinomaniac that said, the taken-on is a date; if the retake happened on the same date, then max of the date is not guaranteed to be the record you want. Ideally, the table would also have an auto-increment primary key - then you could use max of that within groups

Comment: A record can't be test_ID=1 and test_ID = 2.  So the `and`s need to be `or`'s and then you need to count the unique tests having count = 4 grouping by student_ID  but if test 4 is taken twice, failed the first then passed... you'd get that and not want it right?

Comment: Does not taking test 4 count as a failure?  so if there is no Test_4 record for a person but they have 1-3 passed... would you want that student returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RUYC54084)

```
SELECT count(Z.Test_ID), Z.student_ID 
FROM (SELECT distinct student_ID, test_ID, Status 
      FROM table) Z
WHERE (Z.Status = 'Passed' and Z.test_ID in (1,2,3,4))
   OR (Z.status = 'Failed' and Z.test_ID = 4)
GROUP BY Z.Student_ID
HAVING count(Z.Test_ID)  = 4;
```

This works by first ensuring we only have distinct records for each student, status, and test_ID. (derived table Z)

We then evaluate how many passes in tests 1,2,3,4 exist and existence of fails we have for test 4.  if the count is anything other than 4 then we know either they didn't pass the tests 1-3 and fail 4 or they've passed test 4 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not claiming this is fast or most efficient, but it will do the job. Make sure you have the right indices on your table,

```
SELECT s1.student_id
FROM mytable s1
JOIN mytable s2 on s1.student_id=s2.student_id and s2.test_id=2 and s2.status='passed'
JOIN mytable s3 on s1.student_id=s3.student_id and s3.test_id=3 and s3.status='passed'
WHERE s1.test_id=1
AND s1.status='passed'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM mytable s4
    WHERE s4.student_id=s1.student_id
    AND s4.test_id=4
    AND s4.status='passed'
)
```

Comment: I think you want s3 to join critieriaon s3.status not s2.  seems to work otherwise `JOIN mytable s3 on s1.student_id=s3.student_id and s3.test_id=3 and s2.status='passed'` s/b `JOIN mytable s3 on s1.student_id=s3.student_id and s3.test_id=3 and s3.status='passed'`

Comment: I cheated and created a rextester that I tried all 3 answers against :P  I didn't find it on my own. http://rextester.com/GYXXN38292

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
select distinct t1.student_id
from mytable t1
inner join
-- students passed all the 3 tests 
(select student_id from mytable where  test_id in (1, 2, 3) 
 and status = 'passed' group by student_id having count(distinct test_id) = 3 ) t2
on t1.test_id = 4 and t1.status = 'failed' and t1.student_id = t2.student_id
where not exists 
(select 1 from mytable where student_id = t1.student_id and 
                             status = 'passed' and test_id = 4)
```

PS. If a student passed a test (e.g. test 1) but later took it again and failed, the student would be considered as passed. Not sure if that is acceptable.

Comment: good comment.  failure after success may yield undesired results.  but has an issue with test 4.  what happens if the student passes after failing.  you get that student and shouldn't  Feel free to use [Rextester](http://rextester.com/edit/TDUTP45693) to see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can use to meet your requirement is to basically make a pivot table.  Any way you slice it you will probable need to use a subquery, here using the SUM function and CASE statements you can determine how many times each student passed a test.

Then, in your outer WHERE clause you can select only the rows where you got 1 or more 'passed' results for tests 1 through 3, and 0 'passed' results for test 4.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f973fe/4)

```
SELECT student_id
FROM (SELECT student_id, 
    SUM(
          CASE WHEN(test_id = 1 AND result = 'passed')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END) AS "Test1",
    SUM(
          CASE WHEN(test_id = 2 AND result = 'passed')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
           END) AS "Test2",
     SUM(
          CASE WHEN(test_id = 3 AND result = 'passed')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
           END) AS "Test3",
    SUM(
          CASE WHEN(test_id = 4 AND result = 'passed')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
           END) AS "Test4"
    FROM TestResults
    GROUP BY student_id) tr
WHERE Test1 > 0 AND Test2 > 0 AND Test3 > 0 AND Test4 = 0
```

Using this technique you can also determine how many times a student passed or failed a test.  So for example, you can change the CASE statements to 'failed' and return the test columns in the outer query to see the number of times a student failed the test.  For example:

```
SELECT student_id, Test1Fails
    FROM (SELECT student_id, 
        SUM(
              CASE WHEN(test_id = 1 AND result = 'failed')
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) AS "Test1Fails"       
        FROM TestResults
        GROUP BY student_id) tr
```